# Unexpected behaviour with Kotlin Coroutine Error Handling using Retrofit2

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm currently writing unit tests for a small Android app and I'm running into a rather strange error.

I'm using Kotlin coroutines in conjunction with Retrofit 2 to make a simple HTTP GET request to an API. Overall the app is working as expected and I've written tests using a `MockWebServer` which is also working fine except for when trying to test an error response from the API (rather ironic in a way).

Basically, the order in which things gets called is entirely out of whack when I intentionally create an error response.

Below is the test code in question:

```
    @Test
    fun viewModel_loadData_correctErrorHandling() {
        mockServer.enqueue(MockResponse().apply {
            setResponseCode(500)
        })

        viewModel.loadModel()

        assert(!viewModel.loading)
        assert(viewModel.loadingVisibility.value != View.VISIBLE)
        assertNotNull(viewModel.currentError)
        assert(viewModel.errorVisibility.value == View.VISIBLE)
        assertNull(viewModel.model.value)
        assert(viewModel.contentVisibility.value != View.VISIBLE)
    }
```

The `viewModel.loadModel()` function is as follows:

```
    fun loadModel() {
        currentError = null
        loading = true
        model.value = null
        interactor.load(viewModelScope, @MainThread {
            loading = false
            model.value = it
        }, @MainThread {
            loading = false
            currentError = it
            Timber.e(it)
        })
    }
```

And finally the `interactor.load` function is as follows.

```
    fun load(
        scope: CoroutineScope,
        onSuccess: (List<ConsumableCategory>) -> Unit,
        onError: (Throwable) -> Unit
    ) {
        scope.launch {
            try {
                onSuccess(dataManager.getConsumableCategories())
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                onError(t)
            }
        }
    }
```

`dataManager.getConsumableCategories()` just references a call to suspended function created by my `Retrofit` instance.

When running the test in question my output is as follows:

```
2021-09-16T20:05:27.648+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     loadModel start
2021-09-16T20:05:27.648+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Pre Scope
2021-09-16T20:05:27.672+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Post Scope
2021-09-16T20:05:27.672+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     loadModel end
2021-09-16T20:05:27.681+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     onError start
2021-09-16T20:05:27.740+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
2021-09-16T20:05:27.740+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.kenthawkings.mobiquityassessment.ConsumableViewModelTest > viewModel_loadData_correctErrorHandling FAILED
2021-09-16T20:05:27.741+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed
2021-09-16T20:05:27.741+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at com.kenthawkings.mobiquityassessment.ConsumableViewModelTest.viewModel_loadData_correctErrorHandling(ConsumableViewModelTest.kt:104)
...
```

Somehow my `onError` block is getting called AFTER the `loadModel` function is complete. As such, the line `assert(!viewModel.loading)` fails since it's getting called before the `loading` variable is set to `false` in the `onError` callback. I'm using custom rules to make sure everything is running synchronously.

```
    @get:Rule
    val testInstantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    val mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()
```

I've tried using `runBlocking` and `runBlockingTest` (both wrapped around either the entire test or just the `viewModel.loadModel()` line) and it's made no difference. I've tried switching from using a `try-catch` to using a `CoroutineExceptionHandler` and using `kotlin.runCatching` but I always get the same result.

The really weird part is that success response test works as expected and all the statements print "in order".

```
    @Test
    fun viewModel_loadData_correctSuccessHandling() {
        val reader = MockResponseFileReader("success_response.json")
        assertNotNull(reader.content)

        mockServer.enqueue(MockResponse().apply {
            setResponseCode(200)
            setBody(reader.content)
            setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        })

        viewModel.loadModel()

        assert(!viewModel.loading)
        assert(viewModel.loadingVisibility.value != View.VISIBLE)
        assertNull(viewModel.currentError)
        assert(viewModel.errorVisibility.value != View.VISIBLE)
        assertNotNull(viewModel.model.value)
        assert(viewModel.contentVisibility.value == View.VISIBLE)
    }
```

```
2021-09-16T20:05:27.542+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     loadModel start
2021-09-16T20:05:27.550+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Pre Scope
2021-09-16T20:05:27.629+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     onSuccess start
2021-09-16T20:05:27.630+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     onSuccess end
2021-09-16T20:05:27.630+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Post Scope
2021-09-16T20:05:27.630+0200 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     loadModel end
```

I'm fairly new to Kotlin coroutines and but I've done a bunch of Googling on the matter and no one else seems to have this issue so I can only assume I'm doing something very silly here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using custom rules to make sure everything is running synchronously.

The rules that you've used change the execution behavior of the `AndroidDispatchers.MAIN` dispatcher and the LiveData-related executors.
Retrofit implements `suspend` functions through the `Call.enqueue` method which uses an executor provided by OkHttp and is not guaranteed to be synchronous.

The way to solve this is by taking the `Job` object returned by `scope.launch` and calling `.join()` in your tests, this ensures the coroutine finishes before you try to assert on its behavior.

> The really weird part When running my success response test everything works as expected and all the statements print "in order".

This is actually caused by an implementation quirk of Retrofit. The library author actually has written a blog post about it: [Jake Wharton - Exceptions and proxies and coroutines, oh my!](https://jakewharton.com/exceptions-and-proxies-and-coroutines-oh-my/).

Basically Retrofit's `suspend` support **cannot** return synchronously if it has to throw an exception, it always has to go through the dispatcher.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that I also implemented a custom `ThreadExecutor` on which to execute requests in my `OkHttp` client:     `OkHttpClient.Builder().dispatcher(Dispatcher(CurrentThreadExecutor())).build()` (purely for use in my tests of course).

Comment: This seems to have worked thank you! I modified my `load` and `loadModel` methods in my `interactor` and `viewmodel` respectively such that they return the `Job` object created by the `launch` declaration. I then call `join` on my `viewModel.load()` method and wrapped it in a `runBlocking` Coroutine.